# What's the meaning of 'of' in : the government 'of' the people?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, vocabulary

> Democracy is the government **of** the people, by the people, and for the people.

‘*Of*’ being generally translated into this Korean word: ‘[의](http://dic.daum.net/word/view.do?wordid=kkw000202851&q=%EC%9D%98)’, which has over ten meanings, I don’t get the meaning of ‘*of*’ well. I get the idea that ‘*of*’ in the example above seems to have one of these two meanings: ([RHD #1](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/of?s=t)) **possession** (the people *possess* the government), (RHD #2) **source** (the government *comes out of* the people).
Which of them or what any other meaning do I have to get?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Wikipedia article on the [Gettysburg Address](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gettysburg_Address) points to several sources which may have inspired Lincoln's phrase; these suggest two different interpretations:

- William Herndon, Lincoln's law partner, claimed that Lincoln had been particularly taken by a sentence in a sermon by abolitionist preacher Theodore Parker: “Democracy is direct self-government, over all the people, for all the people, by all the people.” “Over all the people” suggests that *of the people* signifies that the people are the direct object of this government—a very common construction, as when we speak of the education **of** children.
- Daniel Webster said in a very famous speech, the *Second Reply to Hayne*, that the Federal government was “made for the people, made by the people, and answerable to the people”, and went on to say “This government, Sir, is the independent offspring of the popular will. It is not the creature of State legislatures; nay, more, if the whole truth must be told, the people brought it into existence, established it ...”. This suggests that *of the people* signifies that this government arises from the people—an old construction, now little used, but still common in 19th-century literary and rhetorical discourse.

A third possible source, Chief Justice John Marshall in *McCulloch vs Maryland*, a decision which become a keystone of Constitutional interpretation, marries both these readings: Marshall wrote that "The government of the Union [...] is, emphatically and truly, a government of the people. In form, and in substance, it emanates from them. Its powers are granted by them, and are to be exercised directly on them, and for their benefit."

Herndon is an authority for Lincoln's knowledge of the Parker sentence; and Lincoln, as a lawyer and a student of the Constitution and of the political debate over its interpretation, was undoubtedly familiar with the Webster and Marshall passages. I incline toward understanding the phrase ambivalently, as Marshall uses it: a government **of** the people is one which emanates from the people and is exercised **on** them.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possession or source, but rather *scope* - Democracy is the government of the people (not the plants, animals, etc).

It's probably closest in definition to sense 7 in [Collins](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/of): *about, concerning*

Comment: Whhhhat? This doesn't seem correct to me. I've always thought it was "source". The government is made up from the people. The government is comprised of people. Now I'm hunting for references.

Comment: That's possible. But in this context - while keeping it relevant to wider contexts, rather than trying to mind-read - it's at least a combination of the possibly expressing some kind of composition.

Comment: @PrestonFitzgerald: If you consider the full expression then that interpretation would be redundant because the idea of being made up from the people is already covered by "by the people"

Comment: That occurred to me after I wrote my first comment @slebetman. I've just always assumed it was emphasis by way of repetition. I guess I don't know why I've thought that though.

Comment: @PrestonFitzgerald: StonyB's answer shows that both may be correct. Indeed "by the people" itself has two possible meanings: source and creator